# How to find download link from javascript code?

Tags: javascript

Please help me to find the download link from this code or from this website.

I want to download videos from bottom of this website: http://fa.ifilmtv.com/Series/Content/9382

```
data-video="Http://77.66.40.15/hls/'+ langE + ID_Serial + '/,'+i+','+i+'_320,.mp4.urlset/master.m3u8"></div><a class="play-movie" ><i class="fa fa-play">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
element.getAttribute("data-video");
```

Comment: Thanks bro, can you explain more? I want to download the videos from bottom of this website: http://fa.ifilmtv.com/Series/Content/9382